# Alterar outra classe (CSS) noscript

Tags: html, css, html5

Olá, no código abaixo quero alterar a cor da classe **imagem_selecionada** ao passar o mouse na classe **imagens**.

O exemplo do código funciona passando o mouse na **area_de_imagens**, editando não consegui devido a eu não ter estudado, se possível gostaria que me recomendassem livros css, obrigado.

```css
<style>
 .galeria{
  position: relative;
 width: 600px;
  height: 700px;
  background:black;
 }
 .galeria .area_imagens{position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
 .galeria .area_imagens .imagens{
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:15px;
  background:orange;
  float:left;
 }
 ul .imagem_selecionada{
   position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
  top:100px;
  left:0px;
  }
 .area_imagens:hover ~ ul .imagem_selecionada{
  background: yellow;
 }
</style>
```

```html
 <div class="galeria">
  <div class="area_imagens">
  <div class="imagens"></div>
  <div class="imagens"></div>
  <div class="imagens"></div>
  <div class="imagens"></div>
  <div class="imagens"></div>
  <div class="imagens"></div>
  <div class="imagens"></div>  
  </div>
  <ul>
 <a href="#"><img src="" class="imagem_selecionada"></a></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara então vai estudar, vc acha que alguém fazendo por vc vai resolver seu problema? Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V de uma resposta qui não vai te levar a lugar nenhum...

Comment: Tudo que eu aprendi foi pela web, mas existem divergências que não batem, exemplo seria um navegador funcionar e outro não acredito que somos todos manipulados e ninguém cria nada inovador, recomenda algum livro?

Comment: Olha ai https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRhM6sMOTfg&list=PLwXQLZ3FdTVGf7GUtiOFLc_9AXO25iIzG 30 aulas de CSS3 de graça pra vc

Comment: irei visualizar e ver se aprendo +, valeu o compartilhamento (y)

Comment: Você quer que muda a cor da imagem ou da area da imagem?

Comment: Boa tarde cara, eu quero que ao passar o mouse nas imagens que estão com background:laranja mude a cor da imagem_selecionada de blue para yellow

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa é que o elemento `ul` só pode ter como filhos diretos elementos `li`, ou seja, você não pode colocar a tag `a` como filho direto da `ul`. Teria que ser assim:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="" class="imagem_selecionada"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Outra coisa é que no CSS você só consegue acessar um elemento a partir de outro se esse elemento for um filho (direto ou não, que também pode ser chamado de *descendente*) ou um irmão.

Na estrutura do seu HTML você não conseguirá acessar o elemento `.imagem_selecionada` a partir dos `.imagens` porque eles não são nem descendentes e nem irmãos, ou seja, hierarquicamente não há nenhuma relação de uns com o outro (no máximo, a grosso modo, são elementos *primos*, mas o CSS não considera elementos primos).

A saída seria alterar a estrutura de modo que os elementos `.imagens` sejam irmãos do elemento `ul` onde está a `.imagem_selecionada` (o que seria mais complicado devido ao fato de estar utilizando flexbox com overflow) ou usar JavaScript, como mostro abaixo:

```js
// seleciona todas as .imagens
const imagens = document.querySelectorAll(".imagens");
// faz um loop adicionando os eventos de entra e sai do mouse
for(let img of imagens){
   img.onmouseenter = img.onmouseleave = function(e){
      var cor;
      if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
         cor = "yellow";
      }else{
         cor = "blue";
      }
      document.querySelector(".imagem_selecionada").style.background = cor;
   }
}
```

```css
.galeria{
   position: relative;
   width: 600px;
   height: 700px;
   background:black;
}
.galeria .area_imagens{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   overflow-x:scroll;
   overflow-y:hidden;
   max-width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.galeria .area_imagens .imagens{
   position: relative;
   min-width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin-left:15px;
   background:orange;
   float:left;
}
ul .imagem_selecionada{
   position: absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:blue;
   top:100px;
   left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="galeria">
   <div class="area_imagens">
      <div class="imagens"></div>
      <div class="imagens"></div>
      <div class="imagens"></div>
      <div class="imagens"></div>
      <div class="imagens"></div>
      <div class="imagens"></div>
      <div class="imagens"></div>  
   </div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="#"><img src="" class="imagem_selecionada"></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

> Repare que foi excluído do CSS o trecho abaixo:

```
.area_imagens:hover ~ ul .imagem_selecionada{
   background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo e dedicação em responder essa minha dúvida, perfeito. Perco muito tempo sem saber mas nesse mês vou arrumar um livro e estudar intensamente css depois javascript. (y)